# Error: Http failure during parsing for https://site/update/

Tags: python, json, django, angular, postman

I am writing a backend of an application which uses angular in frontend and Django in backend. There is a feature in application which wants to edit some information of an existing entity in the database.

I have written the API for it. The API uses a stored procedure to update the database. I have tested the API using the POSTMAN tool by sending RAW JSON data and it works. I can see the data getting updated in the database table.

But when I try to send the data through application frontend, I see the data is updated in the table but in the application frontend I am seeing an error:

Error: Http failure during parsing for https://site/update/

What is this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: In which format you are sending data form angular to DJango? angular httpClient uses default `response-type: json`

Comment: Sending data in json format

Comment: give you api address i will put it to angular httpCLient

Comment: Can you tell me how to put it to angular httpClient, the api address wont work for you

Comment: return this.http.get(this.streamURL, { responseType: "text"}); try like this